# Does OpenSSL API provide an easy way to check certificate revocation?

Tags: openssl, tls1.2

I am new to the library so I might not know what I'm on about.
But I'm making a basic TLS connection on the client like so:

```
//...
// >> standard TCP/IPv4 connect(...) <<
//...
SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations(ctx, cert, 0)
ssl = SSL_new(ctx);
SSL_set_fd(ssl, socket);
SSL_connect(ssl);
```

This is all fine and dandy. After I simply check with:

```
bool valid = SSL_get_verify_result(ssl) == X509_V_OK;
```

I believe this does some basic checks like if the certificate chain is trusted and expiration checks but not if the certificate supplied by the server has been revoked or not. Is there an easy way to check this connection/certificate from here?

---

**openssl version:** 1.1.0b

**cipher suite:** ECDHE-RSA-AES-GCM-SHA

Comment: You should read about CRLs and OCSP.

Comment: You have to be careful about revocation checking in real time. Its ripe for a DoS on your application as it tries to fetch a 100MB+ CRL. OSCP responders are better, but they have problems like being stale or offline when you need them. [Stapled Responses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OCSP_stapling) are probably most useful, but it still has some gaps. Also see Peter Gutmann's [Engineering Security](http://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/~pgut001/pubs/book.pdf). My apologies if you were aware of some of these things.